# Update ItemId from Orderline table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to update the `ItemId` from the `Orderline` table.

**Orderline** table

```
OrderlineId 
SKU 
ItemId
```

**Item** table

```
ItemId 
SKU
```

This is the result I want to achieve

Orderline Table

```
OrderlineId  SKU      ItemId
1            SKUabc   NULL
2            SKU13    NULL
```

Item Table

```
ItemId       SKU
10           SKUabc
11           SKU13
```

RESULT:

Orderline Table

```
OrderlineId  SKU      ItemId
1            SKUabc   10
2            SKU13    11
```

So I need to get all data from `Orderline` with `ItemId` is NULL then loop that data then query Item table using `Orderline.SKU` then update `Orderline.ItemId`

Currently, I have this code but it is not working yet.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateOrderlinesItemId]
AS
    DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
    DECLARE @ItemCursor CURSOR;
    DECLARE @SKU int;
    DECLARE @Item int;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 
            ol.OrderLineId, ol.ItemId
        FROM 
            [OrderLine] AS ol
        WHERE 
            ol.ItemId IS NULL

    OPEN @MyCursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @SKU

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ItemCursor = CURSOR FOR
            SELECT TOP 1 ItemId 
            FROM [dbo].[Item] 
            WHERE SKU = @SKU;

        CASE 
           WHEN @ItemCursor IS NOT NULL
              THEN UPDATE [dbo].OrderLine 
                   SET ItemId = @ItemCursor 
                   WHERE OrderLineId = @MyCursor.OrderLineId
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @ItemId
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END
```

Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: To begin with, you need to OPEN your `@ItemCursor` cursor and close it when the inner loop is completed. Secondly, it is not clear (at least to me) what is it that you wish to achieve (the phrasing of your question is not clear; perhaps you could add an example of the outcome).

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that returns a single, atomic value - it **cannot** be used to conditionally execute code - for that, you need to use `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need a simple `update`:

```
update OL set
  ItemId = (
    SELECT TOP 1 I.ItemId 
    FROM dbo.Item I 
    WHERE I.SKU = OL.SKU
  )
FROM dbo.OrderLine OL
WHERE OL.ItemId IS NULL
```